# why does globals [ x ] pass editor checks but globals [ E ] gives error closing bracket expected?

Tags: netlogo

Is my copy of NetLogo broken?  It's been working fine. Then suddenly today it does this:

If I open a new model in NetLogo 6.1.1 and put in simply

```
globals [
  x
]
```

and hit the editor check-mark, it works fine.  But if I change x to E, like this:

```
globals [
  E
]
```

and run the editor check, I get a "closing bracket expected" error?

If I then add an x to the E, like this

```
globals [
  Ex
]
```

it works fine again.   I manually typed this, so I don't think my E has some invisible hidden backspace or who knows what. It's just a capital E.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I tried NetLogo 5.2.1 and also got an editor check warning, "expected name or ]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`E` is a reserved keyword - NetLogo is case insensitive for keywords (so FALSE is false is FaLsE etc). So you are accidentally accessing the `e` for Euler's number. Note that it should have changed colour to purple in the editor (indicating a reporter) when you entered the code.

Comment: Thanks so much,Jen!  I always try to avoid probable reserved words like "value" or "range", but I forgot that "e" might be one.  The colors purple and black are hard for these eyes to tell apart, especially when I'm not looking for it.   Do you know if there's a list of reserved words somewhere?

Comment: there's the dictionary at https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html and all the words are at the top (providing an index) in groups, but I don't remember ever seeing anything like an alphabetical list

Comment: That will have to do then.   There are definitely a few reserved key-words that are not in the dictionary -- not very many I hope, but a few.   I ran across one last week.

Comment: If you find something is missing from the dictionary, please open an issue at https://github.com/netlogo/netlogo/issues